# Why am I getting this UnsatisfiedLinkError with native code?

Tags: java, native

I have a library called HelloWorld.so and a program HelloWorld.java with this content:

```
class HelloWorld {
     private native void print();
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new HelloWorld().print();
     }
     static {
         System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
     }
 }
```

Now when I try to run HelloWorld.java I get this error:

```
$ /usr/java1.4/bin/java HelloWorld
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no HelloWorld in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1491)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:788)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:834)
        at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:7)
```

Any tips?

Comment: If your using Linux(Ubuntu terminal), Then please have a look on http://saurabhsharma123k.blogspot.in/2017/07/java-jni-and-cc-from-command-line.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mmyers Thank you for responding. We found out that all we had to do was change System.loadLibrary to System.load and pass the full path + filename as argument, worked like a charm.

Even before doing so, we tried using the "-D" parameter and setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH but we weren't successful.

Go figure! :)

Thanks again,
Karen

Comment: That's exceedingly strange. loadLibrary should behave identically, except that it requires the library to be on the path. Which is what the -Djava.libary.path is supposed to help with.

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem and fixed it by renaming my library to `libHelloWorld.so` and following Michael Myers's suggestion. I'm on Arch Linux 64-bit.

`HelloWorld.c`:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

/* shamelessly stolen from the book 'The Java Native Interface: Programmer's
   Guide and Specification' */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_HelloWorld_print (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

`HelloWorld.java`:

```
class HelloWorld {
     private native void print();
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new HelloWorld().print();
     }
     static {
         System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
     }
 }
```

Building and testing:

```
$ javac HelloWorld.java
$ javah -classpath . HelloWorld
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux HelloWorld.c -o libHelloWorld.so
$ java -classpath . -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld
Hello World!
```

**tl;dr: put `lib` at the beginning of the library's filename**

Comment: tl;dr just saved my day

Comment: worked like a charm. my JAVA_HOME wasn't set so I had to use the full path

Comment: `-Djava.library.path=.` Did the work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I think some points are helpful when getting this error:

1. Check consistency of function name in *.c files and generated files (*.h)
2. Name of jni library based on OS.
   Ex: In HelloWorld.java,`System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");`

   - Solaris: `libHelloWorld.so`
   - Linux: `libHelloWorld.so`
   - Win: `HelloWorld.dll`
   - Mac: `libHelloWorld.jnilib`
3. When running, add `-Djava.library.path=PATH`. `PATH` to place where you put your jni library

Here is my reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/moonocean/entry/a_simple_example_of_jni

Answer (score 7):

Where is HelloWorld.so located? You probably need to specify its parent directory using the command-line parameter `"-Djava.library.path"`.

For example, if it's in `"/path/libs/HelloWorld.so"`, add `-Djava.library.path=/path/libs` as an option when invoking `java`. For instance, it's `"-Djava.library.path=lib"` on one of my projects.

**Edit:** Dan Dyer points out that the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also can be used for this.

Comment: Does the .so extension need to be explicitly stated also?

Comment: Edited to clarify (it's actually the path to the folder containing the .so file).

Comment: An alternative is to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.